# Agregar complemento a XML de factura electrónica

Tags: c#, xml, serialización

Estoy intentando crear un xml para la facturación en México pero tengo un problema al serializar el xml, específicamente con la nomina.

Generé las clases a partir de los xsd que el sat proporciona y veo que la clase "comprobante", que es la factura, tiene una propiedad llamada "complemento", que es un array de XmlElement y donde se indica la nomina.

Lo que hago actualmente es serializar la clase que contiene los datos de la nomina, agregando el namespace correspondiente, la convierto a un array de XmlElement y la asigno a la propiedad, después serializo la clase "comprobante" que es la principal (factura).

Con eso ya tengo generado el xml con su complemento, pero la etiqueta donde está la nomina le agrega el atributo del namespace y comparando el resultado con otros xml ese namespace no va en la etiqueta de la nomina, va en la etiqueta del raiz, que también lo contiene. Si no serializo la nomina con el namespace no me agrega la url, pero tampoco el prefijo "nomina", el cual es requerido, ¿Como puedo agregar el complemento con prefijo pero sin namespace?

Saludos

```
//Aquí serializo la nomina
var stream = new MemoryStream();

var xmlSerializeNomina = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Nomina));
var xmlNameSpaceNom = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
xmlNameSpaceNom.Add("nomina", "http://www.sat.gob.mx/nomina");
var doc = new XmlDocument();
using (var writer = new XmlTextWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
{
     writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

     xmlSerializeNomina.Serialize(writer, nom, xmlNameSpaceNom);

     stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

     doc.Load(stream);
}
//La asigno como arreglo de XmlElement
xml.Complemento.Any = new XmlElement[] { doc.ImportNode(doc.DocumentElement, true) as XmlElement };


//Aquí serializo lo que es la factura en el archivo xml
var xmlNameSpace = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();

xmlNameSpace.Add("cfdi", "http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3");
xmlNameSpace.Add("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");

xmlNameSpace.Add("schemaLocation", "http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/3/cfdv32.xsd http://www.sat.gob.mx/nomina http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/nomina/nomina11.xsd");

 var xmlSerializeFactura = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Comprobante));

 using (var xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(xmlPathFile, Encoding.UTF8))
 {
     xmlTextWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

     xmlSerializeFactura.Serialize(xmlTextWriter, xml, xmlNameSpace);
 }


< nomina:Nomina xmlns:nomina="http://www.sat.gob.mx/nomina">
  Otras etiquetas...
< /nomina:Nomina>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para que el namespace no salga en la etiqueta nomina, debes incluir ese namespace también en la raíz:

```
xmlNameSpace.Add("nomina", "http://www.sat.gob.mx/nomina");
```

De ese modo los namespace aparecen sólo en la etiqueta raiz.

Answer (score 0):

Agregar el namespace del complemento (child) en el comprobante (root) no elimina el namespace duplicado en el complemento.